# How to disable fuzzy on django translations?

Tags: python, django

I don't want to use fuzzy tag. Is it possible?

For example;

When i added new sentence or word translations , generally fuzz automatically wrap it. But i don't like it.

```
#: frontend/src/components/language_consts.js:74
#, fuzzy
#| msgid "Patient Address"
msgid "Patient's address?"
msgstr "Adresse du doctor"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because of the software you use to translate your strings. `fuzzy` means that the translation needs reviewing. Mark the translations as reviewed and it should disappear.

Comment: Yeah, but i don't want it. If i added new something, it should be msgtr empty. We can detected empty translations and than fill it.

Comment: Hum, I don't understand, this is clearly a translated file you are showing here

Comment: Generally, fuzzy doesn't correctly match. I think fuzzy should be optional.

Comment: Again, fuzzy is a **comment**, about the state of the translation

Comment: See this screencap of PoEdit, a translation software. Toggling this button enable or disable the "fuzzy" mark. https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1DWKAwhjxfs726JjE2Y8cRnPSHUP27ZLV